# Which is the subject in the following sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

**There are lots of reasons why the road shouldn't be built**

Answer :
Lots of reasons = the subject  ✔️

There is the subject   ❌ ❌ ❌

There or here is never the ( subject ) many books confirm this idea

Sorry for my question

If million people say there = the subject, I will not be satisfied, because of one reason : If (there) is the subject, so why the verb follows must agree with the noun comes after there ?

Perhaps many say that there = **dummy pronoun or empty subject** . OK still the real subject which agrees with its verb, is the noun that comes after there or here.

In many instances the word ( there ) is adverb refers to a place.

The book there is mine.  = adverb refers to a place

There is a little coffee left for you. = available  ( i.e. found )

Even in our speech in Arabic we mean the same.

I know there are many faults with English language because many things with its grammar are still debatable.
Because I love the English language, I really came to here to discuss this matter of grammar with native speakers only especially the ( US ).
Thank you all
With my regards

**Attachment  Here is it the rule from two books of grammar.**

[image]

It is also here from Cambridge  (( 2 minutes ago )) I found
There’s a woman waiting outside who wants to talk to you. (The real subject is the woman – she is waiting outside.).

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/dummy-subjects

Comment: See [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+lots+of+reasons+why%2Care+many+reasons+why&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Care%20lots%20of%20reasons%20why%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20many%20reasons%20why%3B%2Cc0) showing that *There are **lots of** reasons why...* is far less common that *There are **many** reasons why...* (or ***several*** for a slightly less "emphatic" version). My advice would be to stick with ***many*** unless the context is *very* casual / informal.

Answer (score 2):

> *There are lots of reasons why the road shouldn't be built.*

This is an existential construction, where "there" is a dummy pronoun functioning as subject of the sentence.

We know that "there" is the subject because it occurs as subject in an interrogative tag:

> *There are lots of reasons why the road shouldn't be built, **aren't there**.*

Only pronouns are admissible in a tag like this, so not only do we know that "there" is a pronoun, we also know it's the subject.

Further evidence that existential "there" is the subject comes from the fact that it occupies the basic subject position before the verb, and in subject-auxiliary constructions it occurs after the auxiliary, as in:

> ***Are there** lots of reasons why the road shouldn't be built?*

Incidentally, the expression "why the road shouldn't be built" is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question) functioning as complement of "reasons".

Comment: Thank you So, you @ BillJ  say ( there ) = the subject or the dummy subject. I know many can answer in this way and I never agree with such answer. I want the ( real subject ) not the dummy one . I can offer you many good tips from books written by good grammarians. This analysis I don't want.

Comment: @AhmadMohammad There is no doubt at all that "there" is the grammatical subject of the sentence, for the reasons I gave in my answer. Note that when talking in terms of grammar, 'subject' is a grammatical term, not a semantic one. The expression "lots of reasons why the road shouldn't be built" may be considered a 'displaced' subject, even though there is no simpler counterpart.

Comment: How about **Lots of reasons exist for the road not to be built.**?

Comment: The subject would be "lots of reasons".

Comment: I quite like the way you point out *we know that "there" is a pronoun* (and *we also know it's the subject*) simply by virtue of the fact that ***Only pronouns are admissible in a tag like this***. Obviously that might not be much help to a non-native speaker who doesn't ***know*** that only pronouns can be used in such tag questions. But even though most native Anglophones were probably never *explicitly* told / taught this fact, we all know *implicitly* that it's true (even those native speakers who've got no idea what "pronoun" means in the first place! :)

Comment: Sentences beginning with "there" and "here" 
When a statement begins with one of these words, the verb will come before the subject. 
To find the subject of this kind of sentence, drop the word there or here. Then put the rest of the words in their natural order. Just remember that "there" or "here" can never be the subject of a sentence: 
Inverted : Here arrive ((the guests)) on time.   the guest = subject
Natural : The guests arrive on time.
 Inverted order: There is someone in the room. 
Natural order: Someone is in the room.

An Introduction to English Grammar Syntax - Page 21

Comment: remember that "there" or "here" can never be the subject of a sentence: An Introduction to English Grammar Syntax - Page 21  https://books.google.iq/books?id=YTBaDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA21&dq=grammar++%22there%22+or+%22here%22+can+never+be+the+subject+of+a+sentence&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi2pfiVy771AhUgg_0HHdmCBJoQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=grammar%20%20%22there%22%20or%20%22here%22%20can%20never%20be%20the%20subject%20of%20a%20sentence&f=false

Comment: @AhmadMohammad I'm sorry but you are completely wrong. You have ignored the syntactic facts that I stated in my answer. Your example "Here arrive the guests on time" is not an existential one, but a different construction. This is a case of inversion, where the subject is "the guests", But there is no inversion in your original example.

Comment: @AhmadMohammad Note also that the book you cite gives no syntactic evidence for "there" not being the subject.

Comment: It is not only one book but also hundreds books

Comment: @BillJ  You completely wrong Here it is from Cambridge  There’s a woman waiting outside who wants to talk to you. (The real subject is the woman – she is waiting outside.).   https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/dummy-subjects    ?????

Comment: @AhmadMohammad That's nonsense. We are talking about the **GRAMMATICAL** subject, which is "there". You are a non-native speaker, who should learn from English native speakers who teach grammar. You haven't understood anything that I've told you Do not post any further comments in this thread..